# How do I lock a Flask endpoint, so that only one user at a time can access it?

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask server with a multitude of endpoints, e.g.:

```
@app.route('/project1/bench1')
def bench1_dashboard():
    return send_from_directory('templates/project1/bench1.html')
```

The point is, I'm making a UI, that allows for control over specific things on bench1 without having to use remote control. (Another flask server is running on bench1 serving as client.)

My goal is to somehow get flask to only allow one user to access this endpoint at once.

Additional info:

- the communication is in rest API
- the route of the communication always starts from the HTML site's JavaScript, goes through the server, arrives to the client and anything backwards is just replies.

On the client side of things I managed to get the HTML site to send a notice on the bench's website page being closed. Meaning I have a way of telling if the user currently using the site disconnects.

I also made a dictionary on the server side for locks:

```
locks = {
   "bench1" : "unlocked"
}
```

and modified the endpoint so:

```
@app.route('/project1/bench1')
def bench1_dashboard():
    if locks["bench1"] == "locked":
        return render_template('bench_in_use.html')
    else:
        locks["bench1"] = "locked"
        return send_from_directory('templates/project1/bench1.html')
```

If the page is closed, another endpoint gets notified, and changes the lock to unlocked.

Unfortunately, the part where it would block the second user from opening the site does not seem to work.

Is this related to how threading works in flask?

Comment: I guess you could run a single, completely separate *Multiprocessing Manager* task, external to Flask. That process would then contain a *Multiprocessing Lock*. Your Flask endpoints could connect to it and acquire and release the lock to control access. There may be an easier way, but this should work at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one route to do a lock and a different route to do an unlock, you could try to using a threading lock as below:

```py
    import threading
    
    BENCH_LOCK = threading.Lock()
    
    @app.route('/project1/bench1')
    def bench1_dashboard():
        got_lock = BENCH_LOCK.acquire(blocking=True, timeout=10):
        if got_lock:
            return send_from_directory('templates/project1/bench1.html')
        else:
            return 'resource locked by someone else; try to unlock first'

    @app.route('/project1/bench1_unlock')
    def bench1_dashboard_unlock():
        BENCH_LOCK.release()
        return 'released lock'
```

Note that once the lock is acquired, someone will need to eventually unlock the lock. For docs on aquiring locks, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock.acquire

Note that originally I thought you wanted locking only while the route was running in which case you could have used the code below:

```py
    import threading
    
    BENCH_LOCK = threading.Lock()
    
    @app.route('/project1/bench1')
    def bench1_dashboard():
        with BENCH_LOCK:  # will only allow one user at a time to run below
            return send_from_directory('templates/project1/bench1.html')
```

Comment: Two questions with this:

1) I don't know which lock to unlock in case of a page closing, unless I check which client sent the information, in which case I need to access the lock by it name, which I only have as a string. e.g.: I have a string "bench1Lock", and I somehow need to call bench1Lock with this information. Is that possible?

2) Can I redirect with this solution like I did in the second example?

Comment: The above lock will be active until `send_from_directory` finishes or returns an error and then will automatically unlock. Redirects will work fine for the above since it is only active during the call to `send_from_directory`.

Are you asking for something for where a user hits a page to lock something and then later hits a different page to unlock it? That's possible too but I didn't know if that is what you want.

Comment: I understand why my question is confusing. Unfortunately the lock would unlock when the route returns the webpage, and in my case that simply means the page is opened. Thus if the lock unlocks when it returns, it defeats the purpose.